# Serializing and deserializing datetimefield type object (Django app)

Tags: python, django, datetime, serialization

In a Django app of mine, I have a datetime object that I need to serialize and then deserialize. When I try it, I get the error:

> ValueError: time data '2016-05-31T18:57:17.280939+00:00' does not
>   match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

My code to serialize and deserialize is:

```
timestring = time.isoformat() #where timestring is DateTimeField type object, instantiated in Django

timeobj = datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get over the hump? Your guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using `python-dateutil`,  `dateutil.parser.parse` specifically ... the problem is datetime is not timezone aware by default (pytz can help a bit) .. but the +00:00 is whats breaking it... dateutil should handle this correctly ...

Comment: alternatively you could probably do `timeobj = datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")` if its always +00:00

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yea tried that shortcut (it's always +00:00), but still get: `ValueError: time data '2016-05-31T19:10:26.083572+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00'`

Comment: edited my comment. ... your date/time is separated by "T" not space ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: good spot mate. Missed it. This works. Although, would you consider this hackey? Should I go the python-dateutil route? In any case, you should write a full-fledged answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeobj = datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")`

(adds a `T` as the date/time separator, and hard codes the utc offset string part)

will resolve your problem ... and I guess its reasonably safe ... personally I always go with

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
dt_obj = date_parse(timestring)
```

that pretty much always works and does not require me to hardcode the datestring you may need `pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things going on here:

1. Your format string has a space between `%d` and `%H` but the test string has a `T`.
2. Python's `datetime.datetime.strptime` does not work with timezone names/offsets. From the [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

> ```
> classmethod datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
> ```
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to
>   format. This is equivalent to datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string,
>   format)[0:6])).

So you can extract `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second` and `microsecond` but the `%z` directive is for `strftime` only, not `strptime`.

So, in summary:

```
In [18]: datetime.strptime(datetime.today().isoformat(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 15, 20, 20, 581261)
```

but

```
In [22]: datetime.strptime(datetime.today().isoformat()+'+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```